# Should I use 'let' in my REPL Haddock examples?

Tags: haskell, haddock

What is the correct idiom for assignments in [Haddock REPL examples](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html#idm140354810775744)? Specifically, should I use `let`

```
>>> let x = 5
>>> x + 2
7
```

(as is — still — expected by GHCi) or omit it

```
>>> x = 5
>>> x + 2
7
```

(as I can in IHaskell)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you should write your snippets for GHCi, which *de facto* is the standard REPL. As it stands, that means using `let`. Somewhat arbitrary example: [`Control.Foldl` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.1.1/docs/Control-Foldl.html) (libraries by Gabriella Gonzalez provide good examples of "haddocks done right").

Comment: Excellent, thanks! A good model of "done right" is very helpful.